# How Type casting works in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I am new to ruby on rails, I am trying to make operations in the class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base.
I am stuck at point where I need to convert an array of strings to integers.

The code is as below

```
#code from line 151

start_time_parts=start_time.split(":").collect{ |y| y.to_i }

start_time=Time.utc(2015,"jan",1,start_time_parts[0],start_time_parts[1],start_time_parts[2])
end_time_parts=end_time.split(":").collect{ |y| y.to_i }
end_time=Time.utc(2015,"jan",1,end_time_parts[0],end_time_parts[1],end_time_parts[2])

sql1='SELECT `Start_Time` FROM Times'
sql2='SELECT Rates FROM New_billcodes_mock WHERE Category_name=?, Instrument_name=? and Time_zone_name=?'


database_string_start_time =Activity.find_by_sql([sql1,'1'])
#error is here    
string_start_time_parts=database_string_start_time.split(":").collect{ |y| Activity.type_cast(y)}
database_start_time=Time.utc(2015,"jan",1,string_start_time_parts[0],string_start_time_parts[1],string_start_time_parts[2])
```

I get the error message as

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `type_cast' for #<Class:0x4c25340>):
```

Apparently I cannot use to_i method as it is not a method of the class Activity. Please help me if there is an existing method that I can use to convert to integers.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems with this code, but to your specific question: in two places you use the `{ |y| y.to_i }` construct to return integers; why are you not using that in the third instance ( `{ |y| Activity.type_cast(y)}` ) as well? It's the same use case.

Or it would be if Activity.find_by_sql() didn't return an array, which makes splitting it on ':' pretty pointless - but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution to my problem. I used the global method `Integer(`) to convert the string to integer.

```
{|y| y.to_i}
```

doesn't work because `to_i` is not a method in the `class Activity`